# How to Get time from CSV data?

Tags: database, excel, csv

i have downloaded a csv file from my database.
in date field i found 
1416551169
1417798664
1415727808

etc as times

please can anyone please tell how to extract time and date from it like 01:04:2014 10:30 PM

Thank you

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/130691-converting-unix-timestamp-excel-date-time.html

Answer (score 1):

That is a Unix timestamp. You can convert from the Unix time stamp to Excel with the following Excel formula (assuming Unix Time Stamp is in `A1`)

```
=A1/(60*60*24)+"1/1/1970"
```

Answer (score 0):

The numbers you downloaded like like timestamps, probably representing the number of seconds after a particular point in time. Depending on what programming resources you have available, you should have a function to convert the raw timestamp into a person-readable date.